# execute php file from shell script excluding certain time

Tags: bash

I have an Shell script that runs a PHP script every 8 seconds as seen below:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  php /var/www/html/folder1/scripts/processtask.php /var/www/html/folder1/app
  sleep 8;
done
```

I need it to continue this way, however I need it to stop running at 2am until 3am then resume after that on a daily basis

Comment: Isn't this a bit unsafe? If your script is killed for whatever reason, it does not run anymore. Wouldn't it make sense to do the whole scheduling via cron?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cronetab for the same. Check the below link for configuration:

https://www.baeldung.com/linux/schedule-script-execution

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to start the script if not between 2am and 3am (but an allready started script does not need to be stopped) this could be easily checked with an additional if-statement:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do 
  if [[ 2 -le $(date '+%H') && $(date '+%H') -lt 3 ]]; then 
    sleep 60
  else
    php /var/www/html/folder1/scripts/processtask.php /var/www/html/folder1/app
    sleep 8
  fi
done
```